# HAML tags closing unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a haml file with the following:

```
#test-zone
  %p.test-class
    %p
      = "The test works!"
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
<div id='test-zone'>
  <p class='test-class'>
    <p>The test works!</p>
  </p>
</div>
```

BUT what I'm seeing is this:

```
<div id='test-zone'>
  <p class='test-class'></p>
    <p>The test works!</p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

I'm very confused why the

tags are closing themselves. I also don't know what's up with that extra

tag. I do not have too much experience with haml and I have not been able to search out a solution to this problem. Any other information you need from me I am happy to provide.

Comment: You cant have a <p> inside a <p>

Comment: `<p><p></p></p>` is not HTML, it just looks sort of like HTML. [The fine specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) tells you what you can do with `<p>`s. It is important that you're familiar with the HTML standards if you're going to be using HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haml itself is producing the output you are expecting:

```
<div id='test-zone'>
  <p class='test-class'>
    <p>
      The test works!
    </p>
  </p>
</div>
```

However this is invalid HTML, a `<p>` is not allowed inside another `<p>`. You are probably looking at the inspector window of your browser which shows the “corrected” markup. If you view the source directly you will see the expected (invalid) code.

The fix is simply to make sure you use valid HTML, perhaps make the `test-class` paragraph a div instead.

Comment: Thank you sir. Today I learned something basic and important :D